# Unable to read binary file in Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a binary file using the following format

```
with open("binaryfile.bin" , 'rb') as f1:  
    for line in f1.readlines():  
        print(line)
```

It is returning gibberish data like

```
@ ç─+@@@d*d)      

⌡Å2

  
q_ Ç
```

I have verified that the data in the file is correct and I can read it using the od command on the command line

```
od -w8 -Ad -x binaryfile.bin
```

Output:

```
0000000 0011 0022 0066 0066
0000008 0066 0066 0066 0066
*  
0000032 1234 0000 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000
* 
0000080 0000 0000 0000 0056
0000088 0011
```

The problem with the *'od'* command is that when two or more consecutive lines are similar then it replaces them with **"*\n"**. This issue becomes more prevalent if I read only two bytes per line as more data is common.

```
od -w2 -Ad -x binaryfile.bin
```

Output:

```
0000000 0011
0000002 0022
0000004 0066
*
0000032 1234
0000034 0000
*
0000086 0056
0000088 0011
```

I want to read each and every line.

Q1: Can anyone suggest why is the regular *'rb'* command not working?
Q2: Is there an option to read the complete file using the *'ob'* command without removing the common lines?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?  I would expect Python 3 to throw an error with that code.

Comment: `od` has a `-v` flag to prevent removal of duplicate lines.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2.

Comment: @Jasonharper. Thank you.  -v did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

`open("binaryfile.bin" , 'rb')` works correctly, it reads data in bytes, then you print this information to console and it tries to convert these bytes chunk to 'utf-8' format and produces weird characters since you're reading not a text file.

You could use [`binascii.hexify`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) method to convert bytes string to the hex representation you want:

```py
import binascii

with open("binaryfile.bin" , 'rb') as f1:  
  for line in f1.readlines():
    # NOTE: arguments 'sep' and 'bytes_per_sep' are only since Python v3.8
    print(binascii.hexlify(line, sep=' ', bytes_per_sep=2))
```

Comment: Thanks @GProst. I can print the whole file in a single string with  print(binascii.hexlify(line). The print line that you specified is giving this error "hexlify() takes no keyword arguments". I googled but couldn't find examples, where hexlify takes additional arguments.

Comment: Oh, it started to accept those args only starting Python 3.8. (You can see it in the `hexify` method docs)

Comment: Hmm. I am using Python 2.

Comment: Python 2 isn't converting those bytes to UTF-8, it's just passing them to the console unmodified.  The console may be interpreting them as UTF-8 or it may be using some other encoding.